# Updating or adding a Java in the system tab of the Java utility in control panel

Tags: java, windows, path, 32bit-64bit, controlpanel

Problem: I have a 32-bit Java application that is failing in Windows.

I have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java installed on the machine. The example below shows a 32-bit path because I'm not on the machine that has the issue. On the machine in questions the path is for the 64-bit version and I can only assume this is what is causing the issue.

I've tried adding the 32-bit path to the Users tab but that doesn't seem to stick. I apply changes and when I return it has disappeared.

[image]

I've tried adding the 32-bit Java path to the PATH setting in environment variables, no change.

Any tips would be great, **or should the software I'm using be doing something different to utilize the 32-bit Java on my machine?**

Comment: On the affected machine does `HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8.0_25\JavaHome` point to 32 or 64bit?

Comment: Also, did you try running as admin?
`c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin\javacpl.exe`